# Why am I having trouble defining a double in an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, double

My code looks like this:

```
if (gasQuality==87){
    double subtotal = unleaded * gallonsSold;
}else if (gasQuality==89){
    double subtotal = unleadedPlus * gallonsSold;
}else if (gasQuality==91){
    double subtotal = premium * gallonsSold;
}
```

but for some reason the compiler won't recognize 'subtotal' later on. For example if I wanted to apply a tax to the subtotal farther down the code, the compiler reads:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable subtotal
location: class Paniagua_Invoice
                final double cityTax = .0375 * subtotal;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Variable scope, read about it.

Comment: I just did and it makes sense. I'm new and not very good at programming. So what do need to do about it?

Comment: initialize the subtotal variable outside before the if block, whatever initialize inside the block remains in the scope of the block and cannot be accessed outside the block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [`scoping`](http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm). Variables exists inside the block they are declared in (there are also other rules, so you would like to read further on this). Since the first `subTotal` is declared in the `if` block (delimited by `{}`), you can only use it inside that block. To fix this you can try declaring `subtotal` before those `if` statements:

```
double subtotal = 0; // declaration and initialization

if (gasQuality==87) {
     subtotal = unleaded * gallonsSold; // don't declare again
}
else if (gasQuality==89)
     ...
```

Also, you could use a switch statement instead of those `if-else if` statements:

```
switch (gasQuality) {
    case 87:
        subtotal = ...;
        break;
    case 89:
        subtotal = ...;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Improving it even further than the `Switch`-Statement: Add an `Enum` for the `gasQuality` Magic-Numbers.

Comment: I get this:
Paniagua_Invoice.java:48: subtotal is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
                        double subtotal = unleadedPlus * gallonsSold;

Comment: **Note** that inside the `if` statements you don't have to declare it again. In other words, don't put: `double subtotal ...` inside the if statements, just put `subtotal = ...`, since it's already declared outside.

Comment: That make so much more sense. It's running smoothly now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the double subtotal outside the if -else loop.Otherwise the scope of the variable ends in the fp-else loop.Try this:-

```
  double subtotal;

 if (gasQuality==87)
    {
            subtotal = unleaded * gallonsSold;
    }
    else if (gasQuality==89)
    {
            subtotal = unleadedPlus * gallonsSold;
    }
    else if (gasQuality==91)
    {
            subtotal = premium * gallonsSold;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `subtotal` and set it to a preliminary value before the start of the if/else statement.

Comment: The compiler says that the variable subtotal is already defined at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
double subtotal;           

if (gasQuality==87) {
    subtotal = unleaded * gallonsSold;
} else if (gasQuality==89) {
    subtotal = unleadedPlus * gallonsSold;
} else if (gasQuality==91) {
    subtotal = premium * gallonsSold;
}
```

You have a variable scope problem.  Refactoring your code to the above will allow you to use `subtotal` later in the method.

Comment: It returns this
 Paniagua_Invoice.java:48: subtotal is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
                        double subtotal = unleadedPlus * gallonsSold;

Comment: Look very closely inside the `if` statements I have and compare them to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `subtotal` **outside** of these blocks. It's scope is limited to space between `{` and `}`.